# cassandra cql shell window got disappears after installation in windows

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

cassandra cql shell window got disappears after installation in windows?
this was installed using MSI installer availalbe in planet cassandra.

Why this happens ? please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which C* version are you installing? Which windows are you using?

Were you upgrading versions of Cassandra? If that is the case, have you tried to uninstall and install again?

Comment: i am using datastax-community-32bit_3.0.9.msi file to install cassandra. I have uninstalled and repaired using Uninstaller and Re installed. still i face the same problem for cqlsh shell which opens and immediately shut downs. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please go to your Cassandra home directory (most probably in C:\Program Files\dataStax-DDC) and go to logs folder. Please share the content shown in the logs folder.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same issue with DataStax 3.9. This is how I sorted this:

Step 1: Open file: DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml

Step 2: Uncomment the cdc_raw_directory and set new value to (for windows)

cdc_raw_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax-DDC/data/cdc_raw"

Step 3: Goto Windows Services and Start the DataStax DDC Server 3.9.0 Service

Comment: Thanks..Worked Fine.

Comment: Worked for me after a system restart

Comment: Hii In DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf\cassandra.yaml file I don't have cdc_raw_directory inside the data  folder and in yaml. file    can you tell how to add cdc_raw file

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with DataStax Community 3.0.9

**Step 1**: Go to `C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\conf` and open `cassandra.yaml` in notepad or wordpad

**Step 2**: Make sure the file has the following entries. If not, add them and save the file.

`hints_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax Community/data/hints"
data_file_directories: - "C:/Program Files/DataStax Community/data/data"
commitlog_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax Community/data/commitlog"
cdc_raw_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax Community/data/cdc_raw"
saved_caches_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax Community/data/saved_caches"`

**Step 3**: Go to `C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\data` and make sure you have following folders:

commitlog , data , hints, saved_caches, cdc_raw

If cdc_raw folder is missing, create a folder named cdc_raw

After this, run Cassandra CQL shell again. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Goto** `C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\logs\debug.log`  and find the error.

like I facing was same issue, I checked the logs and there was an error

```
ERROR [main] 2018-01-16 14:54:49,359 JVMStabilityInspector.java:82 - Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Could not read commit log descriptor in file C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1516029298188.log
```

i've deleted the the all log files and started server from below location

```
"C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\apache-cassandra\bin\cassandra.bat"
```

once your server is up and running now you can open **Cassandra CQL Shell**

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above worked for me, but this is what did for community 64bit v3.0.9

If you didn't **leave *"Automatically start DataStax Cassandra Community Service"* checked when installing** you'll want to reinstall and leave it checked.

**Goto** `C:\Program Files\DataStax Community` and rename the file cassandra.ymal.orig to cassandra.yaml and leave it in the `DataStax Community` folder and start Cassandra CQL Shell.

Note: I don't know if it's needed but I backed up my cassandra.ymal.orig before doing this.

Also, if anyone could shed light on what the command for windows would be to start Cassandra that would be awesome. It seems at least in part this issue is the service just won't start