# Cqlsh shell is closing itself

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have installed datastax community 2.2.3 and jdk8 but whenever I tried to open cqlsh shell it is getting closed automatically.  Also i have installed python as per the guidelines suggested in https://www.guru99.com/download-install-cassandra.html.
Earlier it worked for me but stops working after few days.  Anybody please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cassandra cql shell window got disappears after installation in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893193/cassandra-cql-shell-window-got-disappears-after-installation-in-windows)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261374/datastax-ddc-service-will-not-start